# Button inside of collectionView Footer not fully clickable in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, footer, collectionview

I am using a reusable footer in collection view, I gave different colours to show how much button height and width is there, but button is not fully clickable on can click on the top part of the button, did everything.

```
class DeSelectContactsFooter: UICollectionViewCell {
var buttonTapped:OnlySuccess?

let selectLabel: UIButton = {
 let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitleColor(AppColors.LightColorTwo, for: .normal)
    button.setTitle("Deselect all", for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = FontsCustom.getFont(.regular, 16)
 return button }()

let underline: UIImageView = {
    let n = UIImageView()
    n.backgroundColor = AppColors.LightColorTwo
    return n }()

 override init(frame: CGRect) {

super.init(frame: frame)
   self.backgroundColor = .green
 addSubview(selectLabel)
   self.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

  // addSubview(underline)
 //  underline.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   //underline.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo:selectLabel.widthAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

   //underline.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true

   //underline.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:selectLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: -17).isActive = true
   //underline.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

   selectLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

   selectLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70).isActive = true
   selectLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true

   selectLabel.backgroundColor = .blue
   
   selectLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

   selectLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
   selectLabel.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onSeeAllTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)}

@objc func onSeeAllTapped(_ sender:UIButton){
print("tapped")
    buttonTapped?()
}
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}}
```

[image]

Comment: Everything you're doing is wrong. A UICollectionViewCell cannot be used as a footer, and a view (such as a button) cannot be added as a direct subview of a cell.

Comment: I have also used UICollectionReusableView type base class, but not working, I registered it as footer class.

Comment: How is it possible only the upper part of the button is working not the full button is working?